# background-size on the html tag

Tags: html, css

My question is regarding the `background-size` CSS property on the html tag.

Why doesn't the following work,

```
html {
background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
background-size: 1500px 1500px;
}
```

Whereas this works,

```
html {
background: url(bg.jpg) no-repeat;
height: 1500px;
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to style the `html`. I think it should be `body`?

Comment: `background-size` and `height` are two completely different things. Were you expecting the same looking background?

Comment: I'd assume a browser issue, because I've tried it and it does work..

Comment: @DavidLaberge I usually give it on the body but wanted to see if it would work on the html tag. So it does not ?

Comment: @Shomz I was excepting it to be same. Could you please tell me why it isn't working ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

They are two completely different things: `background-size` denotes the size of the background image which gets put onto the element, while the element itself can have different dimensions (height 0 will hide it, so no background shown). `height` is the opposite, it specifies the element height, which is not related to the background size you put on it.

See the three examples here (two as I described above, and one to represent the proper way):

```css
html {
  background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ixytPKZeKpM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACjE/NlB_Rp_0Soc/photo.jpg) no-repeat right top;
  background-size: 200px 200px;
  }
div {
  background: url(https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/-ixytPKZeKpM/AAAAAAAAAAI/AAAAAAAACjE/NlB_Rp_0Soc/photo.jpg) no-repeat;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 100px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
#a {
  height: 0;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
#b {
  height: 100px;
  background-size: auto;
}
#c {
  height: 100px;
  background-size: 100px 100px;
}
```

```html
<html>

<body>
  <div id="a"></div>
  <div id="b"></div>
  <div id="c"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Also, I've added the background (and size) to the html element itself, and as you see, it behaves the same way (Mario shrinks to 200x200 without a problem).

---

Read more here:

[background-size](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/background-size)

> The background-size CSS property specifies the size of the background images. The size of the image can be fully constrained or only partially in order to preserve its intrinsic ratio.

[height](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/height)

> The height CSS property specifies the height of the content area of an element. The content area is inside the padding, border, and margin of the element.

Comment: Thank you. That helped a lot. I have one question though. Say the background image has a height 1500px which on my screen is beyond the viewport then I would need to use the `height` property to set a height as well, correct ?

Comment: You're welcome. It's hard to give you the best solution without seeing it first, but let's say 100% height and bg size set to `auto 100%` (or even `100% 100%` if you don't mind the stretching) should work. See this: http://jsfiddle.net/jxa1yn2a/

Comment: I've created a fiddle, http://jsfiddle.net/vinith98/c8vxxktd/, I'm I doing it right ?

Comment: Doesn't look good. Can you explain what are you trying to achieve? I though you wanted a background squeezed to fit the screen. Here is your example with a HUGE image, always fitting the viewport: http://jsfiddle.net/c8vxxktd/1/

Comment: Sorry about that. I just saw the fiddle you created. It sorts out my problem. Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: You're welcome, glad I could help. Here's another one I came up with in the meanwhile - it uses the fixed background, so everything scrolls fine but the background fills the screen and stays there: http://jsfiddle.net/c8vxxktd/2/

Answer (score 1):

Its part of the Box Model, height modifies the  box's height, so you can't see the background past that because the background is for the html box only. You definitely don't want to be changing the html box's height

bg-size might not be working on the browser you are using, check compatibility here:
http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_background-size.asp